# How do i replace wp-post content with variable between two strings in wordpress function?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want a wordpress function to replace iframe src eg: ( http://my1stembed.tld/**variablestring**.html ) to ( http://my2ndembed.tld/**variablestring**.html ) with-in wordpress post content with variable. how do i do this. I need function like this

```
function replace_content($content)
{
$content = str_replace('http://my1stembed.tld/', 'http://my2ndembed.tld/',$content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content');
```

The above function is only replace of fixed eg: ( http://my1stembed.tld/ ) string to ( http://my2ndembed.tld/ ) and not with variable. I'm new in wordpress and have no idea. Any help is highly appreciated.

```html
<iframe src="http://my1stembed.tld/embed/variablefilename/" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

to

```html
<iframe src="http://my2ndembed.tld/embed/variablefilename/" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You don't want variablestring ?

Comment: @baptiste I need dynamic variablestring with string (eg domain replace) from all posts of wp site. Consider i want replace domain1.tld/embed/*/ to domain2.tld/embed/*/ . Sorry about my English.